# carousel doesnt work after adding items

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

The home page on my app has a swipable carousel

```
`{
               xtype : 'carousel',
               id:'myCar',
               autoDestroy:false,
               styleHtmlContent:true,
               padding:'0 0 0 0',
               height:100

  }`
```

I have a painted listener function on my view which add items to my carousel dynamically.

```
`var store = Ext.getStore("inspirationStore");
            var car = Ext.getCmp('myCar');




            var items = car.getItems();
            //destroy all items within this container before populating
            if (items.length > 1){
                for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
                        items[j].destroy();
                }
            }


                for (var i = 0; i < store.getCount(); i++){
                    var item = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
                                            html:'<p class = "inspirationMessage"><b>'+ store.getAt(i).data.message + '</b></p>' + '<p class = "authorName"><b>' + store.getAt(i).raw.Author__r.Name + '</b></p>',
                                            cls:'carouselPanel'
                                        });
                    car.add(item);
                }`
```

The carousel works fine the first time ,But when I go To another page then come back to my home page my carousel doesnt swipe. I could see that items are added but the carousel is not working the way it should. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can remove all panels with the car.`removeAll(true)` function

Comment: Tried that but didnt make any difference `//destroy all items within this container before populating
         car.removeAll(true);
      
          var items = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < store.getCount(); i++){
           var item = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
                    html:'<p class = "inspirationMessage"><b>'+ store.getAt(i).data.message + '</b></p>' + '<p class = "authorName"><b>' + store.getAt(i).raw.Author__r.Name + '</b></p>',
                    cls:'carouselPanel'
                   });
           items.push(item);
          }
                
          car.add(items);`

Answer (score 0):

use `setItems( Array/Object items )` which 
Sets the value of items.

[docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-method-setItems)

Comment: its looks like the items are being added but the carousel is not swipable. Is there a configuration I need to set for it to be swipable again?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding items in loop try this:

```
            var items = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < store.getCount(); i++){
                var item = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
                               html:'<p class = "inspirationMessage"><b>'+ 
                                 store.getAt(i).data.message + '</b></p>' +
                                 '<p class = "authorName"><b>' + 
                                 store.getAt(i).raw.Author__r.Name + '</b></p>',
                               cls:'carouselPanel'
                           });
                items.push(item);
            }
            car.add(items);
```

Comment: Still have the same problem. Im thinking of destroying that carousel and creating a new one to replace it with.

Comment: Destroying and creating again would be expensive so before destroying cache it locally & use it again to create OR instead of destroying just try hide and show, may be it refresh this scrollable thing.

Comment: how could I cache it? Right now im just using the same id "car"

Comment: You can set content into application level variable and then remove that content from DOM by destroy method.

Comment: Something weird is happening. when I tap the little cirlces for the carousel, the carousel changes slides but its still not swipable.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another transparent panel masking this carousel?

Comment: I dont think so. I call car.removeAll() before populating the carousel

Comment: Is is possible to make a panel or some other component act like a carousel?

Comment: You can have horizontally scrolling panel which looks like carousel but it doesn't snap at every page instead it flows freely till the end

Comment: what if I use card layout?

Comment: I don't think card layout is something you need here.